# Matching the last digit or digits after a forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

In a JavaScript function in my Rails app, I'm trying to get the id of a recipe.  Looking inside the event object like this

```
 e.delegateTarget.baseURI
```

produces the uri, the last number of which (after the forward slash) is the id I want.

```
http://myroute.com/users/2/recipes/6
```

Of course, that id could be much longer in the future, so I need to be able to get all the digits after the last forward slash.

I tried to get the last id this way

```
var uri = e.delegateTarget.baseURI
var re = /^(.*[\\\/\d])/;
var recipe_id = uri.match(re);
```

The matched slash is supposed to be the last one because .* matches greedily, and then I look for any digit. This is all wrong. I'm not very experienced with regular expressions. Can you help?

Comment: `url.split('/').pop()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do this would be to use string.split()

```
var uri = "http://myroute.com/users/2/recipes/6",
    splituri = uri.split('/');

recipe_id = splituri[splituri.length - 1] // access the last index
```

Edit:

Even easier with the .pop() method, which returns the popped value

like elclanrs said.

```
var uri = e.delegateTarget.baseURI,
    recipe_id = uri.split('/').pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the special character `$`, which means end of input:

```
re = /\d+$/; //matches one or more digits from the end of the input
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a good resource on JavaScript regular expressions.

Comment: Yeah that's true. I guess if anticipating more than just digits after the final forward slash, doing .split('/').pop() looks more elegant.